# What does the dialog related to Nanami's quote in the last episode of Bokura Ga Ita mean?

Tags: japanese-language, bokura-ga-ita

In the last scene of the final episode of *Bokura Ga Ita* (ep. 26), Yano repeats a quote that Nanami made in an earlier episode. The quote was

> "it all equals out".

In the earlier episode, where the quote originated, Nanami was explaining to Yano how

> he may not have anyone he loves, but there are people who really love him and thus "shouldn't it all equal out?"

Now, back to the final scene. He repeats the quote

> "it all equals out" and questions it. He says, "it didn't all equal out," and that "it ended up more equal...**on the positive side.**"

I've watched two different translations of the scene and I am still confused. I originally thought it was basically saying

> 'you love no one, but someone loves you a lot, so it equals out', so I'm not understanding the "sides".

What exactly is "the positive side"? Did he simply just mean

> *I loved no one, Nanami loved me dearly, and it ended up being on the "side" of me loving Nanami?*

Or is there more to it?

---

Note that this isn't a question about "how it ended". This is a question about the literal meaning of the final lines in the anime. I suspect it might be something lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer follows when Yano entered the train:

> "Because I met Takahashi. I lived to meet Takahashi."
>
>  In the end, the positive side is that at last Yano admitted he doesn't feel lonely anymore because he has Nanami.

Here is the original dialog in Japanese

> 七美　「どこにいてもどんなにさみしくてもつらくても
> 　　　　ここで七美が想ってることを忘れないでね。
> 　　　　矢野は絶対、ひとりじゃないから」
> **矢野　「プラマイゼロ？**」
> 七美　「え？」
> 七美　『矢野のすごくすごく好きな人はもういないのかもしれないけど
> 　　　　それはさみしいことなのかもしれないけど、
> 　　　　でも矢野のことをすっごくすっごく好きな人間がいるってことはそれって
> 　　　　プラマイゼロじゃないかなあ。だからひとりだと思わないでね』
> 矢野　「そうじゃなかった」
> **矢野　「ゼロじゃなくてプラマイプラスだったよ**」
> **矢野　『高橋と出遭ってから、俺は高橋と出遭うために生きてきた』**
>
> <sup>Dialog source: [Happy☆Lucky's blog entry (Japanese)](http://mirumo.serika.ciao.jp/?eid=622539)</sup>

In the original Japanese scene, Nanami used the term "[plus-minus zero](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plus-minus-zero.2680854/)", in which Yano replied with "plus-minus plus".

Also, the main point of Nanami's quote is more about

> loneliness, deeper than just "someone who likes/is liked by another". Nanami felt that Yano was feeling lonely after his previous girlfriend had left him, but since Nanami liked Yano, he shouldn't be feeling lonely anymore, hence "it all equals out". But Yano couldn't move on despite that.

However, after having gone through all of this, Yano finally realized that he was wrong, hence "it ended up [...] on the positive side".